# Assembly: how does this algorithm know when to stop

Tags: algorithm, loops, assembly, mips

This is a pretty easy code, but i was wondering how this algorithm could know how to stop himself.
I mean, is there a way i can tell the program to stop when it reaches the end of the last array (forth) without using a "Branch equal to zero" in the loop section?

```
 .data
 first: .word 1,second
 second: .word 2,third
 third: .word 3,forth
 forth: .word 4

.text
la $t1, first
lw $t2, 0($t1)
add $t4, $zero, $t2
j loop

loop:
addi $t1, $t1, 8
lw $t3, 0($t1)
add $t4, $t3, $t4
j loop

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t4
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Sorry for my bad english, and thank you :)

Comment: Where does this strange _"without using a "Branch equal to zero""_ requirement come from? Just insert some sort of delimiter value and loop until you find it.

Comment: @Michael, well, i need that this programm could work with any possible combination of numbers, can't use any kind of static "delimiter"

Comment: So put a word/byte/whatever before `first` that contains the number of elements.

Comment: There's no way i can stop it without modifying the data segment? that's something i'm trying to understand since i'm studying assembly.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to know when you've finished iterating over an array of undefined size. One way or another you need to encode its size or its end, whether that means modifying the data itself or hardcoding the size into the loop, or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much, i thought there was an easy way to do that.

Comment: There is.... Use a delimiter that's out of range as @Michael suggests or define the number of items as he also suggests.  Those are both very easy solutions.